# Convert the current time to GMT and EPOCH in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In my script, I want to convert the current system time to corresponding GMT and EPOCH time, is there any way to do it ?

IST to GMT with dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS

IST to EPOCH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get your current time in milliseconds since beginning of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) - [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function

   ```
   ${__time(,)}
   ```
2. Get your current time in the given format in your current timezone - the same __time() function with the [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) provided:

   ```
   ${__time(dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss,)}
   ```
3. Get your current time in IST timezone no matter what is your current timezone - [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

   ```
   ${__groovy(new Date().format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"\, TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST')),)}
   ```
4. Get your current time in GMT timezone no matter what is your current timezone - the same __groovy() function:

   ```
   ${__groovy(new Date().format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"\, TimeZone.getTimeZone('GMT')),)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Answer (score 0):

Use 'time' to get the number of seconds since epoch...  Then divide by the following value, depending on what measure you're after:

Human-readable time     Number Of Seconds
1 hour                  3600
1 day                   86400
1 week                  604800
1 month (30.44 days)    2629743
1 year (365.24 days)    31556926

For example, to get the number of days, use this:
${__time(/86400000,pDaySinceEpoch)}